# How to set x axis ticklabels in a seaborn plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am unable to set x axis ticklabels for a seaborn `lineplot` correctly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.rand(8),'b':np.random.rand(8)})
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
g = sns.lineplot(data=df)
g.set_xticklabels(['2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018'])
```

[image]

The years on the x axis are not aligning properly.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Whenever you set the x-ticklabels manually, you should try to first set the corresponding ticks, and then specify the labels. In your case, therefore you should do

```
g = sns.lineplot(data=df)
g.set_xticks(range(len(df))) # <--- set the ticks first
g.set_xticklabels(['2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018'])
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do this by specifying intended interval instead of enumerating the desired x ticks?

Answer (score 24):

#### As of matplotlib 3.5.0

`set_xticklabels` is now discouraged:

> The use of this method is discouraged because of the dependency on tick positions. In most cases, you'll want to use [`set_xticks(positions, labels)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html) instead.

Now [`set_xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html) includes a new `labels` param to set ticks and labels simultaneously:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df)
ax.set_xticks(range(len(df)), labels=range(2011, 2019))
#                             ^^^^^^
```

[image]