# Incomplete plt.show() figure from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I was trying to get a figure from a Pandas
dataframe. Apparently an easy job until I got into
an unexpected problem I cannot get through : the plt.show() produces a figure showing only 20 lines of the 58 contained in the dataframe. Here is the code with output from the python3 interpreter:

```
print(df1) #1
         DDgun  mCSM   SDM  DeepDDG  DynaMut2
VARIANT                                      
G39C      -1.4 -0.56 -0.24    -0.75     -0.66
W63R      -0.6 -0.50  0.21    -0.23      0.42
L66P      -1.0 -0.68 -1.17    -0.92     -0.23
A67P      -0.3 -0.28 -0.67    -0.66     -0.19
E68K      -0.3  0.11 -0.04    -0.14      0.10
R70C      -0.7 -0.09 -0.31    -0.93      0.40
R70G      -0.9 -0.14 -0.03    -0.70     -0.26
R70H      -0.3 -0.58 -0.14    -0.62     -0.56
V71M      -0.5 -0.44 -0.66    -1.59     -0.75
E72A      -0.4 -0.40  0.23    -0.42     -0.28
R73P      -0.4  0.26  0.67    -0.59      0.30
G75D       0.0 -0.35  0.17     0.06     -0.46
S76C      -0.1 -0.23  0.71    -0.30     -0.32
V78G      -3.1 -2.05 -2.26    -2.72     -2.32
A80T      -0.9 -1.62 -1.78    -1.99     -1.80
W82G      -5.8 -3.62 -2.07    -4.79     -3.44
V89M      -1.2 -0.75 -2.13    -3.88     -0.59
S93P      -0.2 -0.12 -1.37    -1.99      0.13
G96D      -0.5 -0.62 -0.60    -2.21     -0.08
K97T       0.1 -0.42 -0.64    -0.50     -0.27
W99C      -2.1 -1.40  0.08    -2.01     -0.70
T101I      0.4  0.02 -0.33     0.13      0.38
G103S     -0.7 -1.26 -2.95    -1.97     -0.84
G108V      0.1 -0.38 -2.64    -1.38     -0.97
P114A     -0.4 -2.47  2.10    -2.13     -2.31
P114L      1.7 -3.03  0.62    -2.57     -0.96
P114S     -1.0 -1.00  3.11    -2.07     -3.05
A117D     -3.2 -2.83 -3.66    -5.70     -1.54
A117G     -2.4 -1.71 -2.21    -3.14     -1.92
A117V      0.8 -0.06 -1.14    -1.55     -0.32
Y119C     -3.1 -1.68 -1.59    -0.29     -1.68
L120F     -1.5 -1.49 -1.48    -1.41     -1.16
L120H     -4.2 -2.63 -1.82    -4.87     -0.74
E122D     -0.5 -1.06 -1.40    -1.04     -0.63
C123S     -0.1 -0.46 -1.17    -0.23      0.33
G124S     -0.5 -0.46 -1.17    -0.23     -0.43
G124V      0.1 -0.78 -2.68    -1.56     -1.08
S125F      1.1 -0.43 -2.29    -1.42     -1.12
L128F     -0.6 -1.10  0.52     0.39     -1.69
F129S     -2.1 -1.63 -0.78    -2.32     -2.22
D132A     -0.0 -2.45 -0.64    -2.32      0.04
A140T     -0.3 -0.17  1.18    -0.30     -0.99
L145Q     -1.9 -1.21 -2.54    -1.04     -1.67
Y155N     -4.8 -1.97 -1.76    -1.70     -2.19
V157F     -1.5 -2.34 -2.39    -4.32     -1.32
R170Q     -0.4 -1.32 -1.32    -3.19     -0.61
W296C     -1.1 -0.41 -0.25    -1.12      0.09
F303S     -2.0 -0.41 -0.10    -0.59     -0.44
P304L     -0.7 -1.03 -0.19    -0.83     -0.22
P318T     -1.2 -0.30 -0.58    -0.66     -0.36
P324L     -0.6 -0.73 -0.82    -1.70     -0.22
Y381C     -3.0 -0.28 -0.58    -1.00     -0.14
K463T      0.0 -1.23 -0.37    -1.55     -0.75
L488P     -3.7 -0.92 -0.16    -2.80     -0.85
P499L     -0.4 -1.09 -2.58    -4.06     -0.32
P499R     -0.9 -0.34  0.58    -0.97     -0.56
F512S     -3.5 -0.30  1.20    -1.01     -2.06
L520F     -0.6 -2.25 -0.83    -1.76     -0.66

ax=sns.heatmap(df1,cmap='rocket')

plt.show()
```

This is the picture I get:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't know the best way to handle this.  But, this is happening because you have too many rows you are trying to squeeze into the figure.  The data is all being represented, it's just that the labels can't all be written out.  You could try to reduce the font of the labels.  Here is how I cheezed it: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 30)); sns.heatmap(df1,cmap='rocket', ax=ax); plt.show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems reasonable.  I manually added the y ticks **AND** the y tick labels.  To improve the appearance, I used `sns.set` to adjust the size of the figure.

```
sns.set(rc = {'figure.figsize':(5, 20)})  # (width_inches, width_height)
ax = sns.heatmap(df1, cmap='rocket')
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(df1)) + .5)
ax.set_yticklabels(df1.index, fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: After ax.set_yticklabels(df1.index, fontsize=12) got ValueError: The number of FixedLocator locations (20), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (58)

Comment: That is why I used `ax.set_yticks` first so that I wouldn't get that error.

Comment: NB in matplotlib 3.5.0+, they've [added a `labels` param to `set_yticks`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70272709/13138364) for this very reason.