# How to customiza Seaborn/Matplotlib heatmap colorbars

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I need to customize the labels and ticks of an
heatmap colorbar obtained by using matplotlib with no success so far.

My data have been already posted and can be found here: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71696085/incomplete-plt-show-figure-from-pandas-dataframe)

My working code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("deltaGdata.csv")

df1 = df[['VARIANT', 'DDgun','mCSM', 'SDM', 'DeepDDG', 'DynaMut2']]
df1.set_index(['VARIANT'],inplace=True)

sns.set(rc = {'figure.figsize':(7, 20)})  # (width_inches, width_height)
ax = sns.heatmap(df1, cmap='rocket')
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(df1)) + .5)
ax.set_yticklabels(df1.index,fontname='DejaVu Sans', fontsize=14.5, fontweight='550' )
ax.set_xticklabels(df1,fontname='DejaVu Sans', fontsize=20, fontweight='550', rotation=90)

ax.set_title("ΔΔG (Kcal/mole)", fontname='DejaVu Sans', fontsize=24, fontweight='700')
figure = ax.get_figure()

figure.savefig('fig.png', dpi=300)
figure.savefig('fig.svg', dpi=300, format="svg")
```

This code produces an heatmap with a colorbar having very tiny ticks and numbers compared with the others
in the final figure.
I found that there is very little documentation about
how to customize colorbars and nothing useful to fix
my problem. I hope to get help also because I think it
would be beneficial for others Matplotlib/Seaborn users.

Comment: Try this: `ax.figure.axes[-1].tick_params(labelsize=20) `

Comment: @r-beginners, thanks a lot i t worked. What [-1] stands for?

Comment: In matplotlib, it is [-1] which means last since the color bar is also created as an axis.

Comment: So, the colorbar is an axis object... I did not know that. If you write these comments as an answer I can vote it if  you are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that it consists of a heatmap and a color bar subplot, with the last subplot specifying the size of the label attribute.

```
print(ax.figure.axes)
[<AxesSubplot:title={'center':'ΔΔG (Kcal/mole)'}, ylabel='VARIANT'>, <AxesSubplot:label='<colorbar>'>]

# Add the following code
ax.figure.axes[-1].tick_params(labelsize=20)
```